# Taking an action AFTER rendering a view with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC app that uses JSP to render pages. Spring has a built-in concept of Interceptors that go off before and after the controllers are invoked, but the postHandle() call still happens before the actual rendering of the view. I have some cleanup that I want to do AFTER the JSP page completes its rendering. Is there any built-in place I can put that without resorting to adding Tomcat interceptors? I like my nice, contained Spring app.

Comment: cleanup in the view or server side ?

Comment: Actually I was storing a secure token in the request attribute, and I wanted to overwrite it after it was sent to the customer to make sure it couldn't be logged by Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `HandlerInterceptor.afterCompletion()` that is triggered after view rendering.
(but ony if `HandlerIntercpetor.preHandle()` was sucefully completed and returned `true`)

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know that was there. Thanks!

Comment: how can I get hold of the view content that was rendered?